# why does this code throw java.lang.StackOverflowError

Tags: java

```
private static double convertCentimeterToInches(double d) {
    double feetPart = 0;
    double inchesPart = 0;
    if (String.valueOf(d) != null && !String.valueOf(d).trim().isEmpty()) {
        feetPart = Math.floor(convertCentimeterToInches(d) / 12);
        inchesPart = Math.ceil(convertCentimeterToInches(d) - (feetPart * 12));
    }
    return inchesPart;
}
```

---

```
06 - 01 02: 25: 08.037: E / XXX(1099): at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java: 352) 
06 - 01 02: 25: 08.037: E / XXX(1099): at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java: 219) 
06 - 01 02: 25: 08.037: E / XXX(1099): at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java: 239) 
06 - 01 02: 25: 08.037: E / XXX(1099): at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java: 230)
06 - 01 02: 25: 08.037: E / XXX(1099): at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java: 1080) 
06 - 01 02: 25: 08.037: E / XXX(1099): at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java: 573) 
06 - 01 02: 25: 08.037: E / XXX(1099): at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java: 856) 
06 - 01 02: 25: 08.037: E / XXX(1099): Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError 
06 - 01 02: 25: 08.037: E / XXX(1099): at java.lang.RealToString.longDigitGenerator(RealToString.java: 269) 
06 - 01 02: 25: 08.037: E / XXX(1099): at java.lang.RealToString.convertDouble(RealToString.java: 111) 
06 - 01 02: 25: 08.037: E / XXX(1099): at java.lang.RealToString.doubleToString(RealToString.java: 59) 
06 - 01 02: 25: 08.037: E / XXX(1099): at java.lang.Double.toString(Double.java: 317) 
06 - 01 02: 25: 08.037: E / XXX(1099): at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java: 1625)
```

I am just thinking on why its throwing stackoverflow error, when everything seems to be perfect in double. There is no conversion happening from `double to int or float` which could result in stackoverflow.

Comment: becouse you have unclear condition for exiting from recursing

Comment: A stack overflow is not caused by any casting between `double`, `int`, `float`, or any other type. A stack overflow is caused almost exclusively by infinite recursion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have an infinite loop, you keep on calling:

```
convertCentimeterToInches(d)
```

with no clause to end the recursion. I have not done this in a while but the correct conversion from centimeters to inches would be:

```
d / 2.54
```

As one of the answers in this previous thread [What is a stack overflow error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/214741/what-is-a-stack-overflow-error) says:

> The common cause for a stack overflow is a bad recursive call.

Answer (score 3):

StackOverflow has nothing to do with conversion from double to int or float. It happens when there's a recursive call that does not have a base condition. A function keeps calling itself again and again and the [stack frames](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack) keep building up until the time that there is no more space on the stack, thus causing a StackOverflow.

Make sure that your recursive functions have a base case.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (String.valueOf(d) != null && !String.valueOf(d).trim().isEmpty())
```

will always be true, so the method will keep calling itself, until it reaches a stack overflow error...

You need to find a condition that will break the recursion at some point.

And if you really want to convert centimeters to inches, it should probably look like:

```
private static double convertCentimeterToInches(double d) {
    return d / 2.54;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have infinite recursion. To fix ...

Replace this

```
    feetPart = Math.floor(convertCentimeterToInches(d) / 12);
    inchesPart = Math.ceil(convertCentimeterToInches(d) - (feetPart * 12));
```

with this

```
    feetPart = Math.floor(d / 12);
    inchesPart = Math.ceil(d - (feetPart * 12));
```